# can't perform this operation for unregistered loader type

Tags: python-3.x, bokeh, pyinstaller

I'm using bokeh for data visualization, and trying to make an executable but it shows an error message of "can't perform this operation for unregistered loader type"

I have tried as a solution of **init**.py to the directory (+subdir) of my script.py, but it's not work.

PS. Win10, Python 3.6.3, pyinstaller 3.4, bokeh 0.12.13

Code:

```
from bokeh.plotting import figure, show

p = figure(width=800, height=400, title="Money")
p.title.text_color = "green"
p.title.text_font_size = "18pt"
p.xaxis.axis_label = "Time"
p.xaxis.axis_label_text_color = "violet"
p.yaxis.axis_label = "Money"
p.yaxis.axis_label_text_color = "violet"
dashs = [12, 4]
listx1 = [1,5,7,9,13,16]
listy1 = [15,50,80,40,70,50]
p.line(listx1, listy1, line_width=4, line_color="red", line_alpha=0.3, line_dash=dashs, legend="Idle")

show(p)
```

Error message:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TOWKC.jpg)

Thx in advance for your help

Answer (score 3):

Ran into the same error using pyinstaller.

This should solve your problem and the problem of not finding jinja2 that will follow:

edit the file: your-python-env\Lib\site-packages\bokeh\core\templates.py

(nb: change your-python-env to wherever you've installed python)

and change the import statements from:

```
import json

from jinja2 import Environment, PackageLoader, Markup
```

to the following:

```
import json
import sys, os
import bokeh.core    
from jinja2 import Environment, FileSystemLoader, Markup
```

Next, find the line where it says:

```
_env = Environment(loader=PackageLoader('bokeh.core', '_templates'))
```

comment this out and replace it with this code:

```
# _env = Environment(loader=PackageLoader('bokeh.core', '_templates'))

if getattr(sys, 'frozen', False):
        # we are running in a bundle        
        templatedir = sys._MEIPASS
else:
        # we are running in a normal Python environment
        templatedir = os.path.dirname(bokeh.core.__file__)

_env = Environment(loader=FileSystemLoader(templatedir + '\\_templates'))
```

(adapted from: https://pythonhosted.org/PyInstaller/runtime-information.html)

What this does is that when the code is frozen, it redirects the jinja2 looking to sys._MEIPASS (which is the folder where your distribution is). Specifically it looks for the jinja2 templates at sys._MEIPASS_templates. When frozen, the **file** points to the wrong location, hence the original problem.

So now, we have to make sure the jinja2 files end up at the _templates folder. To do this we edit the pyinstaller .spec. This works for compiling to one directory or one file. Edit the datas in your .spec file to:

```
a = Analysis(['graphms-gui.py'],
             pathex=['C:\\Users\\choom.000\\Documents\\forcompile270218'],
             binaries=[],
             datas=[(r'your-python-env\Lib\site-packages\bokeh\core\_templates','_templates'),
                    ],
             hiddenimports=[],
             hookspath=[],
             runtime_hooks=[],
             excludes=[],
             win_no_prefer_redirects=False,
             win_private_assemblies=False,
             cipher=block_cipher)
```

What this does is it gets the contents of the core_template folder and copies it to dist_templates. Which is exactly where we've pointed the templates.py to look for the jinja2 files.

This resolved the problem for me with pyinstaller==3.3.1, bokeh==0.12.9 and jinja2==2.10.

Answer (score 0):

Bokeh relies heavily on Jinja2 for its operation. There appears to be a problem between Jinja and Pyinstaller:

https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/issues/1898

So this may simply not be possible unless these downstream issues have been resolved.